# Should we release a delegate in the dealloc method?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, delegates, dealloc

hello I have a small question in objective-C memory management.

I know that if a property is retained we should release it in the dealloc method. ex:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *title;
```

in the dealloc method:

```
-(void) dealloc
{ 
    [title release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

**But if we declare a delegate (using assign)**

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) id titleDelegate
```

**Should we release it in the dealloc method?**

```
[titleDelegate release]
```

Thanks in advance for any tips.

Comment: The solution here is to use ARC and a weak reference.

Comment: +1 for pointing about ARC. I always use it. but in my case I have a project allready written and I am fixing some memory issue in it.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You have not allocated memory or retained .So don't release it. make it nil. You will release memory for an object only if you are the owner of it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to release only what you retain. Assign doesn't increase the retainCount. So, the answer is no.

Answer (score 0):

No. You don't have to and you must not release it. You don't own the object

Answer (score 0):

never release a delegate just put it to nil